# How to access values in an object?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've restated my question. Hopefully it will be easier to understand. Sorry for the confusion.

I have the following object returned as a response to a external service request:

```
QuickEmailVerification\HttpClient\Response Object
(
[body] => Array
    (
        [result] => invalid
        [reason] => rejected_email
        [disposable] => false
        [accept_all] => false
        [role] => false
        [free] => false
        [email] => ***********
        [user] => ******
        [domain] => *******
        [safe_to_send] => false
        [did_you_mean] => 
        [success] => true
        [message] => 
    )

[code] => 200
[headers] => Array
    (
        [Server] => Array
            (
.....etc. etc.

/
```

I can access the [body] node by using

```
var_dump($request->body);
```

And the Array will display on the browser screen as expected.
But how do I var_dump any specific value in the Array?

Thanks for all assistance!

Comment: Your post is confused. The output displayed is not an array but an object of type QuickEmailVerification\HttpClient\Response. You don't supply any code that would have resulted in the structure you posted, and then you start referring to variables without any context to describe what these vars are or where they come from.

Comment: Actually, it is a printout of an array in a browser. Thus it is an array. Humorously, it even says so in the printout. You don't need all my irrelevant code or an explanation of it to answer the question. Which is: how do I assign the values in the array to variables in my code? Specifically, the [body] of the array. Please read the post before downvoting. You obviously weren't trying to address the question.

Comment: No, it is a var_dump of an *object*. That object has one member variable, body and *that* is an array. But we don't even know *what* variable it is a printout of. Is it a var_dump of $request? If so, that would be helpful information. I did in fact read your entire post. If you want a good answer, you'd be wise to edit it and improve it.

Comment: Done. See if that helps and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The output of your var_dump lists all the array keys for $request->body so you should be able to output any single key using array notation like so

```
echo $request->body["reason"];
```

Comment: Indeed that works and thank you. It gives me the screen result of - string(7) "invalid". Is there a way to strip off “string(7) “ by modifying the var_dump?

Comment: Oops! Sorry. Fatigued and did not notice echo instead of var_dump in your response. Works fine. Even without the “ “. Thanks again!